# Closing HttpClient connection before timout is reached

Tags: java, httpclient

I am currently using the HTTPClient 4 to make a POST request to a remote server like this:

```
  HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute( request );
  InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

When the server is not reachable it takes a self-configured amount of time before the connection actually times out. During that periode the execute() is a blocking call.

What i am looking for is a way to cancel the execute() before the natural timeout so that my thread running the execute() is not blocked anymore and will finish gracefully.

I have tried

```
request.abort();
```

and

```
httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

But both of these calls do not interrupt the execute(). Is there any other way to cancel the ongoing connection attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the call in a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and invoke [get with timeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).

Comment: I am looking for a way to stop the blocking execute() not to wait any longer.

Comment: The Future impl will "block" but the calling thread can wait for a ~ precise measure of msecs and then "timeout" and go on its merry way.

Comment: I don't want to wait a precise amount of time i want to stop the execute() from blocking the current thread.

Comment: This will still give you that.  You can simply call with timeout of 0.  The point is this: you say you don't want to block and this will give you that.  Of course, the POST may go through regardless.  So what you want is to cancel that POST attempt, which is a very interesting use-case: why would you want that? Also, the block is most likely /waiting/ for the response and there is NO WAY to prevent that systemically. So a Future is the correct way unless you don't mind digging into the open source HttpClient and adding the extra magic that you want.  It is not there because it makes no sense.

Comment: The usecase is that the user connects to a remote server but it is not reachable that is why he cancels on the state "Connecting..." before a connection has even been established. I don't want to wait for the timeout of the socket until the request thread ends but end the request thread by telling the httpclient to stop trying to connect to the server.

Comment: The Future with timeout will not free up the network resources immediately, so this is not a good solution under load; albeit practical for single-user usecases.

Comment: @mauhiz HTTP is connectionless. Your comment has merit but does not apply here.

Comment: @mauhiz that true but you do not socket open on HTTP. The OP is not asking about a keep alive connection. So this is a all or nothing http client method. There are no resources to shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set connectionTimeout for whatever the max time you want using these methods:`setConnectionTimeout()`

```
setSoTimeout()
```

Comment: I have set the connection timeout before. The problem i am facing is that i want to interrupt the execute() manually before the timeout kicks in.

Comment: Have you closed InputStream? Another question is, 'request' in your question, does that mean HttpGet/HttpPost?

Comment: I have not obtained any input stream because the .execute() is blocking until the socket timout happens in which case a SocketException is thrown. What i want to achieve is to stop the execute (and the thread being blocked) BEFORE the socket timeout kicks in. The request is a POST request.

Comment: Couldn't find anything else. Sorry!